# ActiveMQ Artemis: Propagate credentials from Websocket to STOMP

Tags: websocket, activemq

Can ActiveMQ Artemis propagate basic authentication information (username, password) from a Websocket to the encapsulated STOMP protocol (STOMP-over-Websockets)? The documentation does not really help here.

Answer (score 1):

The broker will not propagate basic auth credentials from a Websocket upgrade HTTP request to the encapsulated STOMP protocol. STOMP has its own `login` and `passcode` headers to deal with authentication. These are part of the [`CONNECT` or `STOMP` frames](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#CONNECT_or_STOMP_Frame). Your STOMP client should have a way to set these.